# OLE Database error

Tags: c#, sql, insert

I want remake this string:

```
string cmdstr = "INSERT into GGG (event_id, device_id, parameter_id, parameter_int_id, time_id, clock_id, user_id) VALUES ('" + s.Substring(0, 45) + "', '" + s.Substring(46, 31) + "', '" + s.Substring(77, 41) + "', '" + r.Match(s.Substring(77, 41)) + "',  '" + s.Substring(118, 19) + "', '" + s.Substring(118, 8) + "',  '" + s.Substring(138, 10) + "')";
```

where i want use parameters.AddWithValue. But i have error.

It's my new code, with error:

```
con.Open();
com.CommandText = "insert into GGG (event_id, device_id, parameter_id, parameter_int_id, time_id, clock_id, user_id) values (@1p, @2p, @3p, @4p, @5p, @6p, @7p)";
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", s.Substring(0, 45));
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", s.Substring(46, 31));
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", s.Substring(77, 41));
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", r.Match(s.Substring(77, 41)));
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", s.Substring(118, 19));
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", s.Substring(118, 8));
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", s.Substring(138, 10));
com.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: What is the error

Comment: Check your parameter names - in the VALUES clause you have `1p`, and in the parameter statements you have `p1`.

Comment: Произошли ошибки во время выполнения многошаговой операции OLE DB. По возможности, проверьте значения всех состояний OLE DB. Работа не выполнена.

Comment: i remake p1, but have the same problen

Comment: Can you add the text of the error to your post? It will make figuring this out much easier.

Comment: Error - 
 
Произошли ошибки во время выполнения многошаговой операции OLE DB. По возможности, проверьте значения всех состояний OLE DB. Работа не выполнена. – Andrey 5 mins ago

Comment: For English speakers, the error text is: PRB: "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors" when opening ADO connection.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure PhillipXT's comment has the answer here. Your variables in the query string (@1p, etc) don't match the tags you're giving them when you add them as parameters (@p1, etc).

When you add a parameter, it essentially replaces that string in the Command Text with the value you provided. In the case, it will attempt to replace "@p1" with the value provided. However, that string does not exist in your command text. In fact, none of your seven parameters match the names in the command text.

It shouldn't matter which location you change the name in, but all seven of those tags must match.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
con.Open();
com.CommandText = "insert into GGG (event_id, device_id, parameter_id, parameter_int_id, time_id, clock_id, user_id) values (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7)";
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", s.Substring(0, 45));
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", s.Substring(46, 31));
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", s.Substring(77, 41));
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", r.Match(s.Substring(77, 41)));
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", s.Substring(118, 19));
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", s.Substring(118, 8));
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", s.Substring(138, 10));
com.ExecuteReader();
```